# Listeners creating memory leaks

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-volley, leakcanary

I have a listener that delivers response from volley to the activity that makes the request:

```
public interface MyListener{
void interpretResponseListener(String response);
void interpretErrorListener(VolleyError error);
}
```

Method that is used to make the call:

```
public static void myVolleyRequest(int request code,MyListener myListener){
...
...
}
```

Activity Code:

```
private MyListener myListener = new MyListener(){
@Override
void interpretResponseListener(String response){
//database changes
}
@Override
void interpretErrorListener(VolleyError error){
//database changes
}

};

myVolleyRequest(100,myListener);
```

I make changes to database in the response.
Leakcanary gives me the following error:

```
GC ROOT com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.<Java Local>
* references com.test.restful.Request.mListener
* references com.test.restfulRestful$44.val$myListener (anonymous class implements com.android.volley.Response$Listener)
* references com.test.Activity$8.this$0 (anonymous class implements com.test.restful.Restful$MyListener)
* leaks com.test.Activity instance
```

Comment: Is this a typo: `new MyListener(new MyListener(){`

Comment: yeah. Sorry for that.corrected the code

Comment: *Listeners creating memory leaks* anonymous class implementation is not a static inner class and it contains the reference to outer class

Comment: Ok. So how do I correct the code. Can you post the correct code.

Comment: do not use: anonymous class ... use normal class which would contains the refereneces to the Activity ... remeber to set the Activity reference to null on onStop

Comment: I am sorry. I didn't understand. How else do you use the listener. Can you post an answer.

Comment: Do you know java at all?? `class MyListenerImpl implements MyListener  { Activity a; public MyListenerImpl(Activity a) { this.a = a; } public void nullTheRefs() { a = null; } }` then on on Activity `MyListener  listener = new MyListenerImpl(this); onStop { listener.nullTheRefs(); }`

Comment: This is an asynchronous call. So basically the user will still be able to move to  a different activity and the call would complete. If I set the activity to null won't it cause discrepancies in the database ?

Comment: This `listener.nullTheRefs()` is a solution but I prefer a `WeakReference` https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html

Comment: @ Selvin i m facing same problem and receving same leak report as posted by @ Rohit Ramkumar how can i solve this